# Add_Meta_box to custom page (formidable edit post)

Tags: plugins, pages, admin, metabox

I'm working on a minor "project" on my wordpress site, and im trying to add a custom metabox to the formidable - edit post(page?) screen. But i seem to be unable to figure out how to do it.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'trustpilot_metabox', 10, 2 );
function trustpilot_meta_box($post_type, $post) 
{
    add_meta_box( 
        'trustpilot-metabox',
        __( 'Trustpilot Invitation' ),
        'trustpilot_metabox_callback',
        'formidable-entries',
        'right',
        'default'
    );
}

function trustpilot_metabox_callback()
{ 
    echo '<div>test</div>';
}
```

url looks like: https://teststore.swe/wp-admin/admin.php?page=formidable-entries&frm_action=edit&id=2222

I have searched google, and seem unable to come up with how to add it to a specific custom page - i have no problem adding it to any custom post or posts in general. 
I figured i was supposed to use the page name, but doesnt seem to work no matter what i put in

Comment: I created a plugin with the meta_box and then called it when the page has a certain page template.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: Your plugin name
Plugin URI: http://www.domain.com
Description: Description
Author: You obviously
Version: 1.0
*/

/**
* Adds a meta box to the post editing screen
*/

include('meta_box/meta_box.php');
?>
```

meta_box.php

```
<?php
$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;
$page_temp = get_page_template_slug( $post_id );

if ($page_temp == 'template_name.php')
{
function home_custom_meta() {
$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;

// checks for post/page ID
    // I REMOVED THE EDITOR BECAUSE I DIDN'T NEED IT
    remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    add_meta_box( 'home_meta', __( 'Homepage', 'home-textdomain' ), 'home_meta_callback', 'page' );

add_action('save_post','my_meta_save');
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'home_custom_meta' );

/**
 * Outputs the content of the meta box
 */
function home_meta_callback( $post ) {
wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'home_nonce' );

// CONTENT OF THE META BOX GOES HERE
}



/**
 * Saves the custom meta input
 */
function home_meta_save( $post_id ) {

// Checks save status
$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'home_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'home_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

// Exits script depending on save status
if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
    return;
}

// Checks for input and sanitizes/saves if needed
if( isset( $_POST[ 'post_value' ] ) ) {update_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_value', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'post_value' ] ) );}

add_action( 'save_post', 'home_meta_save' );
}

/**
 * Adds the meta box stylesheet when appropriate
 */
function home_admin_styles(){global $typenow;
if( $typenow == 'page' ) {wp_enqueue_style( 'meta_box_styles', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'meta-box-styles.css' );}}
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'home_admin_styles' );
}

?>
```

Comment: you're calling `get_page_template_slug` on every front and back end request? you could probably make that more efficient.

Comment: Probably.... How about a suggestion then?